# $_POST Data Only Passed To $_SESSION In Chrome?

Tags: php, forms, session, redirect, post

I've been working on this problem over the last couple days where a post redirect get function works in chrome, but mot other browsers like firefox and safari.

The code below should start a session, set $_POST variables as $_SESSION variables if they exist, assign the sessions to a variable, and then unset and destroy the sessions. Basically anything you pass through this test from should be passed through these variables and echoed out.

I'm trying to get this basic method to work so I can implement server side validation and avoid duplicate submissions with the 303 redirect. Please help I've been stuck for days and can't figure out why it only works in chrome.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

    if(count($_POST) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['testFormText'] = $_POST['testFormText'];

            if(isset($_POST['testSubmit'])){
        $_SESSION['testSubmit'] = 1;}

        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test-form/");
        die();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['testFormText'])){
        $text = $_SESSION['testFormText'];

        $submit = $_SESSION['testSubmit'];

        /*
            Put database-affecting code here.
        */


        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }else{
        $text = null;   
        $submit = null;

    }


    echo '<div class="testForm">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="testFormText"/>
            <input type="submit" name="testSubmit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    ';  

    if (!empty($submit)){
    echo $text;
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
I've tested different sections of the code using vardumps in an attempt to narrow down the problem, which I believe to be:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/test-form/");
        die();
```

From what I've read this is the correct method for a redirect to avoid duplicate submissions. Any idea what's wrong, or can someone please suggest an alternative?

Comment: basic session debugging: check session_id() at every stage. if the value changes, then your session cookie settings are incorrect, and you're "losing" the session, getting a new/empty one each time.

Comment: @MarcB Marc thanks for taking the time to look at this. I have since tested with vardumps and found that the problem is the 303 redirect section. For some reason Chrome handles the request fine, but other browsers do not. Any suggestions?